# Are there any merchants that buy stolen books?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I go all the way to winterhold to sell books. I ugh, stole a lot of books.

No merchants are willing to buy it.

So I should just drop the books?

Comment: Book only useful for reading Lore / alchemy

Comment: The problem is that they’re stolen. Lots of merchants buy books.

Answer (score 13):

There are a few ways you can sell books:

1. Urag at the College of Winterhold (which you already know about).
2. Selling books to a fence (requires some progress in the Thieves' Guild questline - fences will buy anything, even if it's stolen).
3. Getting the [Merchant and Fence perks in the Speech tree](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speech#Skill_Perks). Merchant allows you to sell any item to any merchant. Fence allows you to even sell stolen items to merchants that aren't normally fences.

Comment: Just curious. How the hell those merchant knows the books are stolen anyway?

Comment: Looks like fences won't buy most books. I have a stolen "Song of the Alchemists", but Tonilia won't buy it.